Overfitting in randomForest model in R, WHY?
I am trying to train a Random Forest model in R for sentiment analysis. The model works with tf-idf matrix and learns from it how to classify a review, in positive or negative.
Positive ones are classified with label 1, and negative ones are classified with label 0.
I created a code in R based on the logic of training a model given 2 labels converted to factors, and then dividing the database in training and test datasets.
The matrix is with dimensions 502 x 5477.
What the model does is that also mtry = 5477.
I get accuracy = 1 as output of the code which is strange. Is the problem the logic of the code, or I should add parameters to limit mtry, etc?
# Load necessary libraries
library(randomForest)
library(readxl)
library(caret)
library(e1071)

# Load the original DataFrame with labels
df <- read_excel('~/Downloads/tfidf_r.xlsx')
df$label...2 <- as.factor(df$label...2)

# Split the data into training and testing sets
set.seed(42)
train_indices <- createDataPartition(df$review_id, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
train_data <- df[train_indices, ]
test_data <- df[-train_indices, ]

# Initialize and train the Random Forest classifier with regularization
random_forest_model <- train(label...2 ~ ., data = train_data, method = "rf",
                             trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10))

# Print the model
print(random_forest_model)

# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred <- predict(random_forest_model, newdata = test_data)

Here you can see the output:
Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.9757, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.6067     
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16  


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi, Anisa, and welcome to the site!  A few supplemental pieces of information would be helpful - how much data do you have?  how many factors?  How deep are your trees?

@jbowman I explained at the first part now. Have a look if it helps. Thanks.

Before your last edit, you mentioned that you tried a Naive Bayes model without encountering a similar problem. Have you tried it with the exact same split you used in your code above? In other words, what happens if you add a few lines just after your code above to run a Naive Bayes model on the exact same train_data and test_data sets created for the random forest model? What's the output? That's just a sanity check to see if the problem could come from the data, and with some luck it might give some useful info to answer your question.

@J-J-J when I run Naive Bayes I get accuracy = 0.48. Which seems a normal output. Btw I have 300 reviews which are positive and 200 which are negatives.

@Anisa Just to avoid any misunderstanding, this is the result you get with the exact same train and test sets used for the random forest model?

@J-J-J yes exactly

Apart from the obvious (split your training-test to prevent data leakage), you can also use the nodesize parameter to prevent overfit. For classification, odd values are good, that avoids ties. Try nodesize=3, 5, 7, etc. and measure the difference between your accuracy in training, vs in test. Also, you have a slight class imbalance (300 positive; 200 negative samples), so you want to use stratified sampling when you make the split.

You say "The [TFIDF] matrix is with dimensions 502 x 5477". You have 5477 words (or n-grams)? TFIDF is really intended for Information Retrieval (indexing docs by their rare keywords, e.g. "election boundary", "rulings"), it's not really intended for sentiment analysis, it won't pick up on important stuff like negation, word order involving stopwords: "This movie is *not* worth watching" and "You'd be crazy to give this five stars". Look at simple word-vector approaches instead.

@smci You should probably write an answer addressing those points!

@J-J-J: but the question asks "Why is this (RF) overfitting (on my TFIDF matrix)?" not "What features should I use for simple (positive/negative) classification for sentiment analysis?"

@smci You're right. It sounds like a XY problem, and I've never been sure how to address this kind of situation, even though it  happens quite often on CV for a variety of questions.

Ok let me put it more bluntly. TFIDF sucks brutally for sentiment analysis, so once the OP fixes their data leakage by doing training-test split, they'll find their accuracy isn't very good. They can improve this a little by adding 2-grams and 3-grams, but that won't help much on this tiny 500-sample dataset, not enough to learn the equivalency of "meh", "won't win any Oscars", "save your money". This is because those words can carry either/both positive or negative sentiment, depending on how they're placed in a sentence. So, use simple word-vectors instead.

@smci If adding an answer here is inadequate, I'll ask another question about the problem you point out, because I think your points are largely more relevant than the answer I gave, and should be given much more visibility.

Ok but the basic question "How to do (simple, binary) sentiment analysis on reviews?" has been asked and answered before, I'm looking for a good canonical to cite. But anything with spaCy or word-vector (word2vec or other) would be better than TFIDF.

There aren't any good basic tutorials on CV using word2vec for review sentiment (because that's offtopic to CV). But Googling for "review sentiment analysis word2vec" gives thousands of good articles/tutorials. Also, past Kaggle competitions and tutorials (with notebook) are an excellent place to start.

@smci for information, I used word2vec to produce the matrix to fed to RF model and it doesn't handle well out of dictionary words. Anyway the principal problem I am facing is not the frequency matrix, but the training of the model, for which I don't find enough examples in R, most of them are in Python, which I can't debug with my   actual knowledge.

@Anisa: ok but with word2vec, what was your training-set accuracy? test-set accuracy? % coverage of the vocabulary? better than TFIDF, right? As to Python, you can learn it very quickly. It's useful to know both Python and R.

@Anisa Look at this one: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/demos/rdemo.word2vec.craigslistjobtitles.R, where the task is to find to what category a job title belongs to. They use the h2o package in R, transform their data using word2vec, train a gradient boosting model on it, and then at the end of the script they can predict the category of unseen job titles. Now, I suspect that examples like that are hard to find for R because NLP tools are probably more mature in Python than in R. So Python is a language that you may find useful to learn at some point, as suggested by smci.

@smci I agree with you that word2vec is better, but I couldn't arrive at the point of finding the training-set accuracy because I got errors like: products not found, and the training stoped. That's why I asked the question about the training of the model, because if this part isn't right, I can't experiment with different types of matrixes.

First, note that your approach for classification is not optimal and that word-vector approaches are more suitable for this kind of task, as pointed out by @smci in the comment section (a summary of what they say is: "TFIDF sucks brutally for sentiment analysis"). You might want to look for other questions about adequate methods for this kind of task, or ask a new question about that if existing threads do not address that.
Now, to give you an explanation as to why you have overfitting, it comes from data leakage, as apparently you generated a single tf-idf matrix from the whole dataset, instead of training your model on a tf-idf matrix generated only from the "train" set. If you think about it, your test set is data that you're supposed to not have seen before, so it's illogical to include words coming from the test set into the tf-idf matrix used for training.
To solve this problem, randomly split the very first version of your original untouched dataset into train and test sets, and then create a tf-idf matrix for the train set. Train your model on it. Then you'll have to transform your test set so you can test the trained model on it.
The link I gave above explains how to do that in Python, so you can get an idea of the process. I don't know the details of how to do the same thing in R though, and it's probably more a question for stackoverflow as this part of the problem is really about programming. (Edit: here is an example in R).

thank you for your kind answer. I did this question in SO and they closed it. I didn’t change anything and I posted here. I think I did good as you gave me an insightful answer.

@Anisa Glad I could help! It's possible they closed it because it was difficult to identify if the problem was about programming or about stats. In my experience, questions in a grey area like that tend to be closed. Note that when a question is closed, it does not mean that it's closed forever, you can provide more info to make it a candidate to reopening. For instance, it might have been useful to explain how you generated the tf-idf matrix. Also, a useful thing to remember is that people able to answer a statistical question do not necessarily know the programming language you're using.

I did what you said and I get as output: y_pred <- predict(random_forest_model, newdata = test_data) Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'actually' not found

@Anisa Probably because there are words appearing in the train set that are absent in the test set, and vice versa. That's why it requires some special transformation of the test set. I found this example of how to do it in R, that could be helpful: https://gist.github.com/Zoldin/9e79c047fd8ad7aa6596b0682aca83c6. But I'm not sure if it will work as this code is apparently 7-years old. Otherwise, asking it on SO might be helpful. This is surprisingly difficult to find examples of how to do that correctly in R, compared to Python.

@Anisa Here's another example, more simple: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/text-vectorization.html#tf-idf (section "tf-idf")

When you emphasize absolute predictive accuracy by estimating smooth calibration curves in an unbiased way (using for example overfitting-corrected bootstrap calibration curves) you'll find that the overfitting from random forests is much worse even than what you are currently experiencing.   The worst examples of overfitting I have ever seen have come from random forests.

Do you have any guess how to solve this?

Don't use random forests.  I avoid them at all costs.  Use a solid statistical modeling strategy as I humbly suggest here.
